# ld MinGW link to standard C library

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, mingw, nasm

I have a problem with following code.

```
extern printf
global _main
main:
push msg
call printf
ret
msg db "Hello world",0
```

I assemble this with NASM using `nasm -fwin32 test.asm` Then i link it using `ld test.obj`.
And it tells me "`test.obj:test.asm:(text+0x6): undefined reference to 'printf'`"

How to link my file to standard C libraries? I have ld from latest MinGW.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To assemble code :

```
nasm -fwin32 test.asm
```

Microsoft will prefix functions using the cdecl calling convention with a underscore.
To be match to the C calling convention `printf` should be `_printf`.
The same applies for `_main` instead of `main`.

And link with:

> ld test.obj -lmsvcrt -entry=_main -subsystem=console -o test.exe

Here `-entry` command line option is used to invoking *ld* to specify the entry point for program .
Then use `-l` options to pass `msvcrt` library to the *ld* linker, otherwise you will get an error message, (*undefined reference to `printf'*) which means that the linker did not found the symbol printf in the specified object file produced by NASM.

Here is completed source:

```
global  _main
extern  _printf
section .text
_main:
push msg
call _printf
add esp, 4 ;adjust the stack
ret
msg db "Hello world",0
```

Comment: In the latest version of [TDM-GCC](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/),`libmsvcrt.a` exist in the `\MinGW\lib` directory, and ld successfully link the object file. You can try with `-L<dir>` switch to specify the location:`ld test.obj -L"c:\mingw\bin\../../MinGW/lib/" -lmsvcrt -entry=_main -o test.exe`
Where the path after `-L` is the path to *your* MinGW installation directory.You can also look at [How do I specify the libraries...](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Specify_the_libraries_for_the_linker_to_use) and [MinGW FAQ](http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/cs1300/doc/mingwfaq.html) 3. msvcrt vs crtdll?

Answer (score 1):

I can see several issues with your code. First, you've got an underscore on `global _main` but not on `main:`. These should match. You can either use underscores throughout, or - what I would do - not at all... and for Windows, assemble as `nasm -f win32 --prefix _ test.asm`. This would make it "portable" in that, for Linux, it would assemble, without the `--prefix _` without the underscores. Linux doesn't use underscores on `global`    or `extern` symbols. If, by some chance, you were using OpenWatcom C, you could use `--postfix _`. Yeah, OpenWatcom uses trailing underscores. Yeah, I know they told us C was standardized. but once you get under the hood, this isn't really true.

The other big issue is that after calling `_printf`, you need to `add esp, 4` (or `pop` a dummy register) to "clean up the stack". If you're using Windows APIs, they use the STDCALL calling convention in which "callee cleans up", so you don't want to do this. Mixing C calls (CDECL calling convention) and Windows APIs might get confusing, but should work.

I think Carl has the right idea with using gcc to link it. There's nothing to "compile", but gcc knows the proper command line to ld. `gcc -o test.exe test.obj` will probably be enough (maybe add `-m32` if the latest MinGW expects to be doing 64-bit code). This will link in some "startup code" which calls `_main`. This will increase the size of your executable slightly, and you "might" be able to get along without it, but it's easier to just do it.

In Linux, we can use ld directly (the command line is horrid), but ld is looking for `_start`, not `main`, as the entrypoint. We can tell ld `-e main`, but this entrypoint is not called(!) and there's no possible way to `ret` from it! The situation is probably different in Windows. You would need - as a bare minimum - `-lc` to tell ld that we want those C libraries. Easiest to "let gcc do it" - it won't touch your .asm code (but does link in that "startup code"). Happy Hello World! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a compiler front-end to link:

```
cc test.obj
```

If you *really* want to use `ld` directly (and you shouldn't), use the `-v` flag to `cc` to figure out what complete command line you need.  For example, on my machine, it's:

```
ld -demangle -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.8.0 \
  -o a.out test.obj -lSystem                                  \
  /usr/bin/../lib/clang/4.2/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
```

If I use GCC instead of Clang, it's even crazier:

```
ld -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.8.4 -weak_reference_mismatches                             \
  non-weak -o a.out -lcrt1.10.6.o                                                                          \
  -L/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/x86_64                                      \
  -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/x86_64   \
  -L/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1                                             \
  -L/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/../lib/gcc                                                                       \
  -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1          \
  -L/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/../../..                                    \
  -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/../../.. \
  test.obj -lgcc -lSystem
```